# Qual a melhor plataforma da @StackExchange para assuntos sobre TCC?

Tags: suporte, perguntas

Muitas vezes eu gostaria de tratar assunto de discursões sobre TCC. No meu caso: Engenharia da Computação.

Estou quase terminando a faculdade, tenho ideia do que desenvolver... na verdade... várias ideias, e esse é um dos problemas que não posso levantar como tópico na Stackoverflow.

Para mim, ter uma plataforma que nos ajuda a fazer análise de mercado é de grande importância, como: qual linguagem de programação escolher para uma certa situação, se a minha ideia de TCC é legal para o mercado, entre outros assuntos que levam discursões longas.

Existe essa plataforma aqui na Stack?

Comment: tratar sobre o assunto em questão como algum problema é valido , agora normativas ,pesquisas em relação ao seu problema, não vejo nenhum site da rede que atenda este tipo de solicitação já que o SO é um site de Q&A. Perguntas e respostas para determinados problemas... isso por si só limita perguntas, como por exemplo "preciso de uma pesquisa sobre essa area para o TCC" e assim sucessivamente

Comment: Discussões longas não são produtivas e geralmente se tornam ruídos dentro da plataforma. O que você citou na sua pergunta é justamente o contrário. É bem dificil solucionar um problema que não existe, e as idéias representam apenas 0,01% do seu projeto, todo resto é execução.

Comment: Para assuntos mais informais ou fora do escopo de Q&A entre na [sala de chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) pode trocar ideias com várias pessoas lá :)

Comment: stackoverflow é uma plataforma especifica e não possui múltiplas/diferentes que abram oportunidades para situações diferentes, o máximo que conseguirá é se tentar buscar algo no chat, já citado pelo @rray, e ainda sim será como um pedido, tem gente que vai interessar e tem gente que não vai. Pra resumir, o site aqui só tem um foco Q&A. ;)

Comment: Não entendi os negativos. Isto não é uma sugestão para o site, é um pedido de suporte. Não tem do que vocês discordarem. Pelo contrário, temos é que incentivar quando os usuários vêm aqui no meta tirar dúvidas sobre o site e a rede.

Comment: Essa é uma das críticas em relação ao Stackoverflow @bfavaretto. Estou sofrendo com isso, pois muitos desenvolvedores e moderadores mais experiêntes discordam mandando uma péssima pontuação para nós.
Por exemplo: Perdi ponto por errar algumas palavrinhas, pois estava escrevendo no celular: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/249266/revisions
Já é uma outra questão, para uma outra discursão. Mas levando em conta esse pedido, acho legal levatarem um ponto para avaliar a sugestão. Não que venhamos ficar a vida toda em uma pergunta, mas que venhamos funilar em ideias.

Comment: @bfavaretto concordo, ps: não fui eu.

Comment: @ThiagoCunha De fato aqui não é o lugar pra gente se estender sobre as suas outras críticas. Esse ponto é meio complicado porque o sistema não é claro pros usuários menos experientes. Por exemplo, parece que você acha que o usuário que editou sua resposta foi o mesmo que te negativou. Pode muito bem não ter sido. Também não sabemos o motivo da negativação.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não existe, e a menos que o negócio da Stack Exchange mude bastante, não existirá no futuro.

O modelo de *Stack* pressupõe sites com perguntas objetivas - e respostas objetivas que sejam úteis não apenas no momento em que foram dadas, mas que permaneçam úteis por tempo indeterminado. Análise de mercado é algo que varia muito no tempo. O que é certo hoje pode não ser certo mês que vem. Principalmente na área de tecnologia, onde o lançamento de um dispositivo ou plataforma pode mudar as regras do jogo. Há também o fator de que toda análise de mercado é baseada em opinião.

Já quanto a discussões longas, acredito que praticamente [todos os sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) da rede possuem mecanismos para o fechamento de perguntas por serem amplas demais.

Se você deseja perguntar qual linguagem é mais adequada para uma situação específica, a decisão tem que ser técnica para caber aqui - caso contrário o problema não é nem ser amplo demais, mas sim ser questão de opinião.

Se você quer discutir temas amplos ou baseados em opinião, infelizmente o formato de *Stack* não é adequado para você. Discussões longas, sem término, sem melhor resposta e baseadas em opinião são o domínio de fóruns. O único site que não é *stack* nem fórum, mas que é respeitável, no qual consigo pensar agora é o Quora - mas boa sorte se for procurar uma resposta definitiva sobre qualquer coisa que seja por lá.

Comment: Legal! Gostei da resposta @Renan. Eu amo Stackoverflow e estou gostando a cada dia do sistema gamefication.
Mas existem algumas questões que tenho medo de arriscar, como se profissionalizar em uma linguagem apenas... E se essa linguagem defasar no mercado?
Eu entendo as regras, mas acredito que a busca de opiniões e a soma delas seriam ideais para chegar em minha conclusão.
Uma vez eu fiz uma pergunta no Stackoverflow com relação a melhor linguagem de programação para um problema específico meu, e fui banido, infelizmente!

Comment: @ThiagoCunha Você só é banido da rede se fizer spam nela. Talvez você tenha feito muitas perguntas negativadas, daí o sistema dá uma suspensão temporária.

Comment: @ThiagoCunha não foi banimento, foi "veto", o banimento te impede de fazer qualquer coisa, o veto só te impede de fazer uma ou outra atividade especifica e é baseado na "qualidade".

Comment: Entendi! :)
Estou perdendo pontuação em algumas coisas... e está dificil saber o porque!
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/249266/revisions

Essas situações que estão me bloqueando em alguns momentos!

Comment: @ThiagoCunha não entendi, o que a revisão tem haver com pontuação? O DvD só editou sua pergunta, isso não significa que foi ele que negativou (também não prova o contrário), não dá pra ficar levantando suspeitas, a unica atitude ali do usuário Dvd me parece que é melhorar a sua postagem.

Comment: Sim... não digo ele... até achei legal... mas não sei quem negativou até agora... Só acho que esta totalmente errado esse tipo de avaliação.

Answer (score 3):

Do meu ponto de vista, o SO pode ser muito bem utilizado para auxiliar num TCC, seja ele mais teórico ou prático.

Mas antes de tudo, é importante saber em quais pontos ele pode ser útil ou não.

Num TCC teórico, você primeiro deve fazer sua lição de casa, pesquisar sobre o tema e levantar algumas hipóteses. O SO não é o lugar de perguntar sobre bibliografia ou pedir opiniões (a não ser no chat, talvez). Mas com uma ou mais hipóteses em mente, dentro do campo da Engenharia de Software, você pode fazer perguntas específicas que terão boa aceitação, se feitas corretamente.

Numa abordagem mais prático, a coisa não é tão diferente. Faça sua lição de casa e pergunte especificamente sobre pontos específicos da modelagem ou execução do projeto. Não pergunte, por exemplo, qual tecnologia usar (na maioria dos casos, não importa), mas você pode perguntar, por exemplo, como resolver o problema X na linguagem Y e isto vai te dar uma boa ideia se aquela linguagem resolve bem o problema que você está querendo resolver.

Particularmente, eu acredito que o maior problema de perguntas opinativas e abrangentes demais - as quais são fechadas - decorre do fato de que quem pergunta não pensa ou não se esforça o suficiente antes de fazer a pergunta, isto é, não "faz a lição de casa", então muitas vezes uma dúvida legítima fica enterrada sob os problemas em como ela é expressada.

Só para exemplificar, enquanto perguntas do tipo "como eu faço um sistema X" são quase prontamente fechadas, são mais bem aceitos aquelas em que o autor a apresenta bem o problema, incluindo uma versão inicial da solução ou modelagem e então pergunta especificamente sobre pontos específicos, tais como se isto ou aquilo são práticas recomendadas, se tal solução atende o requisito inicial, etc.

Veja aqui um bom exemplo: [Qual a melhor maneira de se representar um Endereço?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/622/227)

Talvez a mágica seja fazer do seu problema particular algo objetivamente útil para as demais pessoas.